# "display='block'" not keeping my DIVs on the same line

Tags: html, css, block, display

I'm trying to get two DIVs to stay on the same horizontal plane.  I have

```
<div id="timeChanges">

<div id="oneDayChange" class="change">
            One day change 
        <div>
            <div id="downArrow" class="downArrow arrow"></div>
        - 14.961 / -7.66 % 
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="oneWeekChange" class="change">
            One week change 
        <div>
            <div id="upArrow" class="upArrow arrow"></div>
        + 34.863 / 17.851 % 
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

and have tried the CSS

```
#timeChanges {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I've also tried just "block" for the above.  But as you can see, https://jsfiddle.net/Ldk7ovjp/1/, my two DIVs are on different lines.  How do I keep them on the same one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `display:inline-block` on the `change` class seems to work:

```
.change {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/0ozk8L73/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the inline-block to both div elements:

```
.change{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying inline block to the wrong elements.  You have to apply it to the divs you want on the same line.  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ldk7ovjp/2/)

```
#oneWeekChange, #oneDayChange {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below css in the end.

```
 #oneWeekChange , #oneDayChange{
    float:left
    }
```

Full CSS is as below for your reference

```
#timeChanges {
  display: inline-block;
   float:left;

}

.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
.arrow:after {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';

}

.upArrow:after {
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #ccc, #000);

}

.downArrow:after {
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(-120deg, transparent 63%, #fff 63%), linear-gradient(to top, #ccc, #000);

}

#oneWeekChange , #oneDayChange{
    float:left
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add display inline block, make sure to the class change.

```
.change {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

If you want to horizontally divs with id timeChanges, you can use inline-flex or flex.
For example :

```
#timeChanges {
  display:inline-flex;
  //display: flex;
}
```